# What are sockets with bound state on 0.0.0.0

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, socket

I know a listening socket on 0.0.0.0 is listening on all IPv4 interfaces.
But we also see a lot of 'bound' stockets on 0.0.0.0, if we check with `Get-NetTCPConnection` in powershell.
All on high port numbers (63000+) with a both local and remoteaddress of 0.0.0.0, and a remote port of 0.

What kind of sockets can this be?
We see this on a windows web server (2016), which serves a number of websites (IIS).
This server also hosts the ASP.NET state server, which is also accessed from another server in the same network.

When there are about 50-100 users active on these sites, there are about 1000 of these sockets open.
When there's more activity, the number of these sockets also grow.

Comment: These should be [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)

Comment: But is it normal they are bound to 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are ephemeral ports. They always "bind" to `0.0.0.0:<range>` and remote `0.0.0.0:0`. You can also check the setting using `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp`, e. g. on my Windows 10 workstation:

```
Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
-------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

You can change this setting by using `netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=X num=Y`, but usually you shouldn't need to.

[This Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832017/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements-for-windows) lists the defaults per service.